MSI Leopard Laptop won't boot
I have a 3-year-old MSI laptop in great shape, and it sees the USB install but sits there forever (like overnight) just on the MSI Logo and Ubuntu logo spinning forever. It's been wiped completely clean. Ideas? I need it for my certification. Thanks for any help

"it sees the USB install" Please explain what this phrase means. Does it mean it sees the USB Ubuntu installer? Does it mean that you have already completely installed Ubuntu, but the Ubuntu that you installed can't boot? Are you trying to install Ubuntu 24.04? Have you already installed Ubuntu 24.04?

I think the most literal way to read the phrase is that you've installed Ubuntu via the USB  and it sees that. On the other hand what's the point of making us guess?
